# PySpark - MySQL with JDBC - Drop table

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to execute queries using PySpark and push it to MySQL?

**Note:** Not reading or writing, but performing other types of queries:

**DROP TABLE**

```
# Sample below doesn't work
url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.100:3306/temp"
sparkSession.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url).option("user", user).option("password", password).option("driver", driver).option("query", "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.random_people")  # First clean table if exists
```

Comment: for example, first option here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74439747/is-there-a-way-to-just-truncate-a-remote-mssql-table-from-databricks/74441972#74441972

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexOtt. It worked for me. If you want to mark as duplicate, or publish the answer, ill accept it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to just truncate a remote mssql table from databricks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74439747/is-there-a-way-to-just-truncate-a-remote-mssql-table-from-databricks)